# Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ISafeSerializationData'

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I am getting the following exception trying to deserialize a web api call - the message is obscure so I can't understand what is going on - this cast works in other cases not sure what's wrong here:

Exception:

```
  InnerException: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
   _HResult=-2146232828
   _message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   HResult=-2146232828
   IsTransient=false
   Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
   Source=mscorlib
   StackTrace:
        at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
        at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
        at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
        at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract.<>c__DisplayClass1.<CreateSerializationCallback>b__0(Object o, StreamingContext context)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract.InvokeOnDeserialized(Object o, StreamingContext context)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.OnDeserialized(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Object value)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateISerializable(JsonReader reader, JsonISerializableContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
        at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
        at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
        at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
        at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
        at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
        at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.<ReadAsAsyncCore>d__0`1.MoveNext()
   InnerException: System.InvalidCastException
        _HResult=-2147467262
        _message=Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ISafeSerializationData'.
        HResult=-2147467262
        IsTransient=false
        Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.ISafeSerializationData'.
        Source=mscorlib
        StackTrace:
             at System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager.CompleteDeserialization(Object deserializedObject)
             at System.Exception.OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
        InnerException:
```

My code:

```
public SensoriaApiResult<T> PostSensoriaApiResult(object body)
    {
        HttpClient client = SetupClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response;
        response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, body).Result;

        SensoriaApiResult<T> result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SensoriaApiResult<T>>().Result;
        return result;
    }
```

The Json returned:

```
{"StatusCode":500,"APIResult":null,"HttpError":{"Message":"Sensoria API internal error","SensoriaApiErrorCode":983041},"Exception":{"ClassName":"System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException","Message":"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.","Data":{},"InnerException":{"ClassName":"System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException","Message":"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.","Data":{},"InnerException":{"Errors":[{"source":".Net SqlClient Data Provider","number":547,"state":0,"errorClass":16,"server":".","message":"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_UserBase.ClosetItems_Catalog.Products\". The conflict occurred in database \"Sensoria.Knowledge.Database\", table \"dbo.Catalog.Products\", column 'ProductId'.","procedure":"","lineNumber":1,"win32ErrorCode":0},{"source":".Net SqlClient Data Provider","number":3621,"state":0,"errorClass":0,"server":".","message":"The statement has been terminated.","procedure":"","lineNumber":1,"win32ErrorCode":0}],"ClientConnectionId":"7b976c29-59ff-491c-a3aa-01750e17cb36","ClassName":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException","Message":"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_UserBase.ClosetItems_Catalog.Products\". The conflict occurred in database \"Sensoria.Knowledge.Database\", table \"dbo.Catalog.Products\", column 'ProductId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.","Data":{"HelpLink.ProdName":"Microsoft SQL Server","HelpLink.ProdVer":"11.00.3128","HelpLink.EvtSrc":"MSSQLServer","HelpLink.EvtID":"547","HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl":"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink","HelpLink.LinkId":"20476"},"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClassb.<Reader>b__8()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1 executing, Action`1 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nOnError\nSystem.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection\nVoid OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean, System.Action`1[System.Action])","HResult":-2146232060,"Source":".Net SqlClient Data Provider","WatsonBuckets":null},"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction, Boolean throwOnClosedConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update(Boolean throwOnClosedConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__33()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass28.<SaveChanges>b__25()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nUpdate\nEntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator\nInt32 Update()","HResult":-2146233087,"Source":"EntityFramework","WatsonBuckets":null},"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at Sensoria.Models.ShoeClosetModel.CreateClosetModelForUser(Int32 userId, ShoeClosetItem newClosetItem) in c:\\Users\\maurgi\\Source\\Hg\\sensoria-main\\Source\\Web\\Sensoria.Models\\ShoeClosetModel.cs:line 225\r\n   at Sensoria.Models.ShoeClosetModel.CreateClosetItem(Int32 userID, ShoeClosetItem newClosetItem) in c:\\Users\\maurgi\\Source\\Hg\\sensoria-main\\Source\\Web\\Sensoria.Models\\ShoeClosetModel.cs:line 76\r\n   at Sensoria.Api.Controllers.ShoeClosetController.AddNewShoe(Int32 userId, ShoeClosetItem sItem) in c:\\Users\\maurgi\\Source\\Hg\\sensoria-main\\Source\\Web\\Sensoria.Api\\Controllers\\ShoeClosetController.cs:line 79","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nCreateClosetModelForUser\nSensoria.Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null\nSensoria.Models.ShoeClosetModel\nSensoria.Models.ShoeClosetModel CreateClosetModelForUser(Int32, Sensoria.Api.Core.Models.ShoeClosetItem)","HResult":-2146233087,"Source":"Sensoria.Models","WatsonBuckets":null,"SafeSerializationManager":{"m_serializedStates":[{"<InvolvesIndependentAssociations>k__BackingField":false}]},"CLR_SafeSerializationManager_RealType":"System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"},"ModelState":null}
```

The Generic APIResult class definition:

```
public class SensoriaApiResult<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The 
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember]
    public HttpStatusCode StatusCode;
    [DataMember]
    public T APIResult;
    [DataMember]
    public HttpError HttpError;
    [DataMember]
    public Exception Exception;
    [DataMember]
    public ModelStateDictionary ModelState;

    ...
```

}

Comment: Related or duplicate: [Is this a bug in JSON.NET or Entity Framework or am I doing something wrong while trying to serialize a list of Exceptions with JSON.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35900889/3744182).  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40121963/3744182) shows a potential workaround using a custom converter for exceptions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since this question is almost 2 years old, I highly doubt I can be of any help to the original poster, but for anyone googling this error, this is caused by the fact that many entity data framework exceptions do not implement a serialization constructor, and instead rely on the [SerializeObjectState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.serializeobjectstate(v=vs.110).aspx) event (as does System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException, which happens to be the little bugger that has been giving *me* fits for the past few hours). JSON.NET does not properly handle this situation, as documented in [this](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/840) bug report.

Comment: What a time saver. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

Regarding the serialization/deserialization of `HttpRequestException`, this horrible hack fixed the issue for me:

```
string myJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject).Replace("\"SafeSerializationManager\":", "\"_SafeSerializationManager\":");
```

Comment: This worked for me too. Seems like the only way around this right now I could find. You know you are in trouble when your exceptions have exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when I tried to desrialize an exception (which I serialized) with inner exception of type `HttpRequestException`.
This exception can't be deseialized since it has no implementation of `GetObjectData`.

My solution was removing `HttpRequestException` instances before serialization.

Answer (score 1):

If you observe the returned json, representing serialized exception, the interesting part is here:

> ..."InnerException":{"Errors":[{"source":".Net SqlClient Data Provider","number":547,"state":0,"errorClass":16,"server":".","message":"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_UserBase.ClosetItems_Catalog.Products\". The conflict occurred in database \"Sensoria.Knowledge.Database\", table \"dbo.Catalog.Products\", column 'ProductId'.","procedure":"","lineNumber":1,"win32ErrorCode":0},{"source":".Net SqlClient Data Provider","number":3621,"state":0,"errorClass":0,"server":".","message":"The statement has been terminated.","procedure":"","lineNumber":1,"win32ErrorCode":0}],"ClientConnectionId":"7b976c29-59ff-491c-a3aa-01750e17cb36","ClassName":"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException","Message":**"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_UserBase.ClosetItems_Catalog.Products\". The conflict occurred in database \"Sensoria.Knowledge.Database\", table \"dbo.Catalog.Products\", column 'ProductId'**.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.","Data":{"HelpLink.ProdName":"Microsoft SQL ...

Namely this statement:

> "The **INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint** \"FK_UserBase.ClosetItems_Catalog.Products\". The conflict occurred in database \"Sensoria.Knowledge.Database\", table \"**dbo.Catalog.Products**\", column **'ProductId'****

So I would suggest to observe the value of a param `body`, which you are recieving and passing: `PostSensoriaApiResult(object body)`. There could be some `ProductId` which does not exist *(very often **0**, i.e. the default of any `int` property)*

Comment: Thank you for the reply!
I am aware that this is the error - but I would like to cast this information into my type : SensoriaApiResult<T> that has an Exception property so that the client can inspect it.

Unfortunately the deserialization/casting fails and the client is left with an unintelligible exception .. -

Comment: I would say, that the problem is: You should firstly read the response. Deserialize it into some object, catch any exceptions of that process. Implement decision tree - in case that the repsonse contains error instead of expect result. Next, having this info, you should manully (in code) fill your `SensoriaApiResult` with processed information. These will be then properly serialized. I would say... split it into step. not do all at once